# Difference between upvotes (question) on meta and SO

Tags: discussion, reputation

Why is there a difference between reputation score on upvotes(question) on meta-stackoverflow and stackoverflow? When I get an upvote here at meta (on my question) I am awarded +10 reputation, correspondingly I get only +5 at SO?

Is there any specific reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No specific reason.

At one stage upvotes where worth 10 reputation, but in March 2010 this was changed on the trilogy, however it was decided it doesn't matter on MSO, since the purpose of upvotes and downvotes on MSO is different from the rest of the sites. Therefore the change was never made to this site.

You can read more about it on the blog [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/) and [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)